# Query - select multiple rows based on condition

Tags: sql

I'm a bloody beginner (working with Access). Suppose that I have two tables with data:

1. list of students
2. list of extracurricular activities

I have a third table that links these two tables as shown below:

[image: third table]

I want to construct a query that gives me the list of all students that are participating in the same activity as a selected student.
E.g. if I choose Mike, I want to have four rows:

1. Mike - Basketball - 2016
2. Lisa - Basketball - 2021
3. Mike - Football - 2018
4. John - Football - 2020

**sample data**

1. students

| studentFirstName | studentLastName |
| --- | --- |
| John | Mayers |
| Lisa | O'Reilly |
| Mike | Thompson |

2. activities

| activityName |
| --- |
| Basketball |
| Chess |
| Football |

3. linking table

| studentFirstName | studentLastName | activityStartYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Chess | 2017 |
| John | Football | 2020 |
| Lisa | Basketball | 2021 |
| Lisa | Chess | 2019 |
| Mike | Basketball | 2016 |
| Mike | Football | 2018 |

**desired result**

a) Input: John

Output: all students that share a common activity with John

| studentFirstName | studentLastName | activityStartYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Chess | 2017 |
| John | Football | 2020 |
| Lisa | Chess | 2019 |
| Mike | Football | 2018 |

b) Input: Lisa

Output: all students that share a common activity with Lisa

| studentFirstName | studentLastName | activityStartYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Chess | 2017 |
| Lisa | Basketball | 2021 |
| Lisa | Chess | 2019 |
| Mike | Basketball | 2016 |

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you wanna know it from a SQL perspective?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
SELECT /*b.studentFirst, */ 
     a.studentFirstName,
     a.activity,
     a.year
FROM third_table a
JOIN student_table b
ON a.activity = b.activity 
/* AND a.year = b.year -- if needed */
WHERE b.studentFirstName IN ('Mike'...)
```

notes:

- /* */ parts kind of depends on what you really want to do
- as you see activity table is not needed but you could add a join
  to ensure it exists  JOIN activities c ON a.activity = c.activity
  but this is only needed if you need to check the existence
  of the activity

Comment: Some suggestions to improve your answer: As indicated in the output example, the author does not want to match year, so the `-- if needed` part will make it more confusing. Avoid `a.*` and list the fields for good practices. Move the `FROM` clause to a separate line for readability.

Comment: Thanks mate, your proposed solution works perfectly! (:

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
SELECT
   name
   ,activity
   ,year
FROM linkingtable
WHERE activity IN (SELECT activity FROM linkingtable WHERE name = 'Mike')
```

It will return all the activities from the linkingtable based on Mike.

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9aa143bbc8f411918dc497e45678b87c)